# Windows won't show flash drive after Windows Update

Tags: windows, windows-10, usb

My connected USB stick makes a Windows sound like it is recognized but I am not able to see it in Explorer. When I open `MiniTool Partition Wizard` it shows my USB stick as a hard-disk with partitions. I am able to format and edit it. I don't have problems with my usb drivers and they don't need updates.

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: What happens when you remove the USB stick and insert it in another slot again?

Comment: same in every slot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows does not support multi-partition external disks.

Windows will at most show the first partition,
and if this is a Linux partition that it doesn't understand, the results are
unpredictable (but certainly not what you would expect).

Comment: thanks for the explaining! Is this something new in Windows? Because till now I was able to read it (Actually I was making USB back-ups with `Win32DiskImager`) But now I'm not able to select the usb

Comment: You might have better luck reformatting the disk on Windows. FAT32 will be less troublesome than NTFS, on condition that your files are smaller than 4GB, otherwise use exFAT.